# Docker build thinks I'm root

Tags: macos, docker, dockerfile

I'm running the dockerfile found here https://github.com/facebookresearch/pytorch3d/issues/113 but the I keep getting an error on step 2

```
 > [ 2/15] RUN cd ~/Downloads:
#5 0.253 /bin/bash: line 0: cd: /root/Downloads: No such file or directory
```

I'm not running as root but docker keeps trying to access `root/Downloads` instead of my home directory. I'm on a mac if that's relevant.

Comment: You probably are root; most base images run as root, within their containers.  From inside a container you can't access files on the host without special setup, and more specifically from within a Dockerfile you won't be able to access the host's `/Users/*/Downloads`.  Do you have a more complete Dockerfile and a specific thing you're trying to achieve with it?

Comment: The dockerfile is in the thread I linked above. Here is a direct link https://github.com/facebookresearch/pytorch3d/files/4346345/install_Pytorch3D_Dockerfile.txt

Comment: Please edit the question to include all required details in the question itself, not behind links.  See also [ask] in the SO Help Center for what makes a good question.

Comment: @DavidMaze is right default container user is root, Simply in your DockerFile before step 2 with the keyword `USER` change the the user to someone else and make sure the user have the directory you want to get in it using cd (Also use keyword `WORKDIR` for changing the work directory)